# How to handle Event of "Selectable" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is how I create items in **Selectable** in jQuery
isValid = new Array(list.size);

```
var div = document.getElementById("selectable");

for(i=0; i<list.size; i++)
{
    // It should look like that//<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    var properties = list[i].getProperties();
    var aTag = document.createElement("li"); //file name or something as ID
    aTag.setAttribute('class',"ui-widget-content");
    aTag.setAttribute('id',i);

    aTag.innerHTML = properties.fileName; //file name
    div.appendChild(aTag);
}
```

I tried the following two, but they both don't work:

```
 $(function () {
            $("#selectable").selectable();
        });

        $("#selectable").selectable({
            selected: function (event, ui) {
                var x = 0;
                x++;
            }
        });
```

The HTML part which should be filled

```
<div class="demo">
  <ol id="selectable">

  </ol>
</div>
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: You're calling the variable which holds the element with id `selectable` by the name `div`. Is that element actually a DIV? If so, you need to make it a list (UL or OI) as a DIV full of LI elements isn't valid. Show us some markup?

Comment: No problem. I have one other question--what is this variable you have named `list` which has a property named `size`?

Comment: It's some array or collection. I found they were using the event stop: in the last example (Selectable Serialize) on jQuery-ui website and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That one worked!

```
$(function () {
            $("#selectable").selectable({
                stop: function () {
                    var result = $("#select-result").empty();
                    $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {
                        var index = $("#selectable li").index(this);
                        result.append(" #" + (index + 1));



                        $("#play").button("option", {
                            label: "pause",
                            icons: {
                                primary: "ui-icon-pause"
                            }
                        });

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```